# .NET 2.0 won't install Windows 98

Tags: .net-framework, installation, windows-98

I'm trying to install .NET Framework v2.0 on my Windows 98 PC, but when I run the installer, the following error dialog appears twice:

```
The INSTALL.EXE file is linked to missing export OLEAUT32.DLL: 314
```

Then, one more dialog appears with this message:

```
Error creating process <c:\windows\TEMP\IXP000.TMP\Install.exe>.
Reason: A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

The computer does not have any other .NET versions installed.  I have tried copying Oleaut32.dll to the C:\Windows directory and to C:\ but with no success.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: While the answer has been supplied, I do have to ask, why are you still using an OS that was released 13.5 years ago and has been unsupported for a long time.

Comment: .net came LONG after Win98 was released. I highly doubt .net supports win98 in any way other than accidentally.

Comment: That was my original answer but it was wrong. .NET 2.0 IS supported on Windows 98. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx

Comment: @MarcB: The download page indicates otherwise.

Comment: But this question is also off-topic.

Comment: @ChrisBint:  I'm just messing with the computer for fun.  I thought maybe I'd load another OS onto it, or use the DOS part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you have never installed some fairly standard support files and these are included in the following package;

[VBRun60.exe installs Visual Basic 6.0 run-time files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192461/EN-US)

Comment: I installed the runtime and the installer ran perfectly!  Now all I have to do is install Windows Installer and IE 5.01.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Windows 95 original shipped without support for OLE Automation.  IIRC, it didn't become available until 1996.  Consequently, there were a lot of installers that deployed the missing files, oleaut32.dll was one of them.  With the inevitable trouble this causes, they routinely overwrote the Windows 98 version of those DLLs.  Windows file protection came around later to stop installers from doing this.

Or in other words, your Windows install is messed up.  I'll leave the question on how to fix it to your imagination.

Comment: I love this answer...

Comment: If you need to extract this file, EXT.EXE from erd.cab from a Win98 boot disk will search through the CABs on the CD for you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check that you're not installing the **x64** .NET 2.0 version. Ensure you download the **x32** one.

Then, check the [software requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19#system-requirements).

**Supported Operating Systems**: Windows 2000 Service Pack 3, Windows 98, Windows 98 Second Edition, Windows ME, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP Service Pack 2

**Required Software**:

- Windows Installer 3.0 (*except for Windows 98/ME, which require Windows Installer 2.0 or later*). Windows Installer 3.1 or later is recommended.
- IE 5.01 or later: You must also be running Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.01 or later for all installations of the .NET Framework.

**Disk Space Requirements**: 280 MB (x86), 610 MB (x64)

Comment: Good point. Maybe he misses IE 5.01...

Comment: OLEAUT32.DLL is part of the Microsoft Data Access Components. The link you reference also states that if you are doing a server install, you may need 'Microsoft Data Access Components 2.8 or later is recommended.'